# Custom Marker Options in google map

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

Can we make Custom MarkerOptions in google?

I want to use Custom MarkerOptions to show image in Dialog box like  [image]   Containng Name as title, and two image within it.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"></ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="harish"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="7dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_location2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With default MarkerOption i can only get Title , Snippet in dialog box like this:

```
public void addMarkersToMap() {
    mArun = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(ARUN)
            .title("Arun")
            .snippet("Match stat:")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker
                 (BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

[image]

help me with some suggestion .

Comment: This helped in my case ! http://androidfreakers.blogspot.com/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the `setInfoWindowAdapter` method of `GoogleMap` class.

```
GoogleMap mMap;//You have to initialise it.

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                /* 
                Here you will inflate the custom layout that you want to use for marker. I have inflate the custom view according to my requirements.
               */
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_info_window, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                textView.setSelected(true);
                textView.setText(poiPlayerData.getName());
                return v;
            }
        });
```