# Mutiple infowindows in map and not hidden is select off the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markers

I have this method that creates custom markers, but I want the infowindows to be activated if they are more than two and that they do not disappear if it is selected in another part of the map, is this possible?

```
private void mMarker(String direction, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(direction)
            .snippet("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinc));

    CustomInfoWindows adapter = new CustomInfoWindows(MainActivity.this);
    gMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
    gMap.addMarker(markerOpt).showInfoWindow();
    gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            launchPlaceSearchActivityOrigin();

        }
    });
}
```

custom adapter *

```
public class CustomInfoWindows implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

private Activity context;


public CustomInfoWindows(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custominfowindows, null);

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);

    tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
    tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());



    return view;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Since there is only one info window shown at any one time, this provider may choose to reuse views, or it may choose to create new views on each method invocation.**

Try using custom marker and show multiple at a time

[Custom Marker Options in google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873209/custom-marker-options-in-google-map)

Comment: I'm using InfoWindowAdapter